# How many citizens are living in Cornucopia? What's the size of Cornucopia?

Tags: the-ickabog

I want to know how many citizens are in Cornucopia and the size of this country.  Can someone make a proper estimate? A fast horseman can go from one city to another in a day. Evidently it's a small country - but how small?  The size can be used to decipher the number of citizens.

Knowing the number of citizens will allow me to calculate the total icky tax revenue (2 ducats per person).

Comment: They say they needed 10 000 ducats for the Ickabog Defense Brigade. Let's say they need another 10 000 for tax collectors - then total 20 000 ducats. The Ickabog tax is 2 ducats,  so 20 000 ÷ 2 = 10 000  ; which means there are 10 000 people in Cornucupia. Of course I might be entirely wrong - what you think  ?